# How to store two variables from a CSV with two columns?

Tags: powershell, csv

Every pc and user in each CSV row have a connection, is generated from an inventory software.

CSV file:

```
"pc1";"user1"
"pc2";"user2"
"pc3";"user3"
```

newbie CODE:

```
$csv = IMPORT-CSV ~\desktop\report.csv

$computersCsv = get-magicallyColumn1
$usersCsv = get-magicallyColumn2

$i = 0

Foreach ($computersCsv in $usersCsv) {

    W7path = \\computersCsv[$i]\c$\users\usersCsv[$i]\desktop

        if(Test-Path W7){

            "not matters - the size is $size"

            if($size -gt "some bytes"){

            Add-Content ~\desktop\NewReport.csv "THAT MATTERS ComputersCsv[$i] userCsv[$i] $size"
            }
        }

        else{
            "Error! - bad connection"
        }

    $i++
}
```

thx for the help/ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to collect csv rows separately, powershell manages this quite well. Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but here is some help:

```
$csv = import-csv test.csv -Delimiter ";" -Header PCName, User
echo $csv #debug purposes

foreach($item in $csv)
{
    echo "this is the first pc name"
    echo $item.PCName
    $pc = $item.PCName
    echo "This is the first user name"
    echo $item.User
    $user = $item.User

    $W7path = \\$PCname\c$\users\$User\desktop

    if(Test-Path $W7path){

        "not matters - the size is $size"

        if($size -gt "some bytes"){

        Add-Content ~\desktop\NewReport.csv "THAT MATTERS $item.PCname $item.User $size"
        }
    }

    else{
       echo "Error! - bad connection"
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't know why but is not working, I get literally: "this is the first pc name" "This is the first user name" I'm using porwershell v1

Comment: @pedaleo Getting no other errors? Yeah v1 should be able to do it, I won't be able to test it out again until tomorrow when I can get my hands on a pc with PowerShell v1. I'm running v4 on my home and work pcs. Are you copying this whole script and using it as is? You will need to change the path of the csv file etc

Comment: I copied/pasted your code, and works. I haven't access now to my original code but sure that I made a mistake somewhere. Tahnks